# Installing 32bit windows in 64bit UEFI

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, 32-bit, asus-rog-zephyrus

I have a device and a software from the 2000' that only work on 32bit windows OS. I currently have an Asus ROG GA503 that runs 64bit win11.

I wanted to run windows 7 32bit on a USB stick so that I just need to plug it, boot it, launch my software and voilà.

But, to what I understand, My UEFI cannot boot 32bit OS and does not have a CSM nor a Legacy mode. It doesnt recognise the bootia32.efi

Is there a way to "unlock" a legacy mode or CSM on those Asus ROG UEFI?  Or is there any way I can sort of reflash my UEFI?  Or can I force it to boot?

Comment: Does your software require 3D acceleration or other specific hardware access? If not, is there anything else that would make using a virtual machine infeasible?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried running the software with win7 in VMware, but the device is not recognised throught the USB...

Comment: It’s impossible to run Windows 7 32-bit on a system while in UEFI mode on a system with a 64-but UEFI kernel. That capability didn’t get introduced until Windows 8. If the software cannot run within a virtual machine then you are out of luck.

Comment: I assume you have already tried, but windows offers compatibility modes for programs designed to work in older versions of Windows.
And as for the VMs, I haven't used VMware, but I have used VirtualBox, and you **need** to specifically passthrough USB devices to the VM (not only give the VM access to the USB storage). By default, they are isolated from the VM (and that is a feature, not a bug).

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 - It’s a safe bet that the application from 2000, is actually a 16-bit application, if it cannot run on a 64-bit installation of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound - the application runs, but cannot recognise the device. On the app's [website](https://en.trust-power.com/products/electronics/greddy-e-manage-ultimate), it is specified that the software is not adapted for 64bit OS.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 - I'm gonna try to go more in depth with VMware.

Comment: @LeZys - That’s likely a driver problem. You can’t use 32-bit device drivers on a 64-bit operating system. Other than Windows 7, none of those editions of Windows, had a 74-bit edition other than Windows XP 64-bit Edition which was its own separate license edition of Windows (had its own lifecycle separate from the mainstream edition of Windows XP). Your hardware is incompatible with that device due to it’s being incapable of running Windows 7 without virtualization if the application cannot run within a Hypervisor